# Can you touch a Sukkah decoration over Sukkot that extends outside of the Sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot

This Sukkot, we had a rather interesting setup with one of our decorations. We have a chain made out of foam links. We've been building it up for *years* -  it's got over 850 links by now. It's so big that we decided to do something that isn't standardly done - we stretched it out so that it *left* the Sukkah, weaved around for a while over the front door, and then came back and zigzagged around the Sukkah. While it was over by the door, you could *not* see the Sukkah if you were standing by the chain.

Is it allowed to touch the Sukkah decoration that is hanging in the Sukkah if it is also *outside* the Sukkah over Chol HaMoed (since I'm assuming it's muktzah over Chag itself)?

Comment: By touch do you mean move? You are allowed to touch muktzah if you don't move it.

Comment: @robev - I've always learned that you shouldn't touch it, in order to prevent you from moving it, but I suppose that yes, I mean moving it.

Comment: Can you move a Sukkah decoration that’s inside the Sukkah?

Comment: @DonielF - no, my tradition is not to.

Comment: @Mithrandir On Yom Tov and Shabbos at least you happen to be correct that that’s the Halacha. Take a look at OC 638:2 - that’s where that Halacha is brought down, as well as that you can make conditions on your decorations that they won’t be muktzeh. Maybe some commentary there mentions something? I can’t imagine that it would be any worse. You may want to cite the above SA/Rema in the OP.